# Wordpress post validation - I want to make it require AT LEAST one category

Tags: wordpress

A Wordpress post can be assigned to a category. I need a validation hook or a save_post hook and do some logic so a post has to have between 1 and 5 categories selected in order to be saved. There's a **save_post** hook but I don't know how to use it to add extra validation.

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: WordPress kinda does this already -- if there is no category, it assigns it to Uncategorized by default (Though this can be changed in the settings).

This means your validation will always fire because there's always at least one category being selected -- whether the user has selected it or not.

Ultimately this means you're going to have to both disable the default category AND write the validation.